# Laravel migrations run with no error but integer field is not created

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to migrate a migration file. Some integer fields triggered an error:

`$table->integer('age',11)->default('0');`

There were a few of those. After reading other posts, and trying a few things, I changed it to:

`$table->integer('age',11)->default(0)->change();`

This time, no error raised, but the created table miss and those fields!

Please find the whole file below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateReservationAnniversairesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reservation_anniversaires', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id',11);
        $table->string('nom',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('gsm',30)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('prenom',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('email',100);
        $table->integer('age',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->time('heure_debut');
        $table->time('heure_fin');
        $table->string('gateau',100)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('impression',100)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('nbre_enfants',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->integer('acompte',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->text('remarques');
        $table->tinyInteger('salle',4)->default(0)->change();
        $table->time('heure_gouter');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('formule',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('actif',11)->default(1)->change();
        $table->string('couleur',30)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('rappel',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->integer('confirm',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->integer('pizzas',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->integer('sandwiches',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->string('options')->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('annif_confirme',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->string('created',30);
        $table->string('modified',30);
        $table->tinyInteger('confirm_enfants',1)->default(0)->change();
        $table->tinyInteger('invitations',1)->default(0)->change();
        $table->string('adresse')->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('invitsEnvoyees',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->float('paiement')->default(0)->change();
        $table->string('paiement_methode',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->integer('enfants_presents',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->integer('parts_gateau',11)->default(0)->change();
        $table->float('options_montant')->default(0)->change();
        $table->string('deco_salle',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('formule_theme',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('photos',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('grimage',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('clown',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');
        $table->string('sculpture',50)->nullable()->default('NULL');

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('reservation_anniversaires');
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the error they were triggering? Have you tried using `$table->integer('age')->default('0');` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set length, but you can use different types of integer:

```
$table->bigInteger()
$table->mediumInteger()
$table->integer()
$table->smallInteger()
$table->tinyInteger()
```

You can check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to set the length of the `age` column integer type.

Unfortunately, the second parameter is not for setting the column length. You can set the column length for `char` and `string` types only, but not for `integer`.

`Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint` :

```
integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
```

Automatically, migration will create the `integer` type with length `11`. So you don't have to bother.

```
$table->integer('age')->default(0);
```

---

> There were a few of those. After reading other posts, and trying a few things, I changed it to:
>
> ```
> $table->integer('age',11)->default(0)->change();
> ```

The `change` method is only used to update the column, not to create the column. You won't see the error, because migration ignore it.

To update the table, you must have a schema like this:

```
Schema::table('reservation_anniversaires', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
});

// Schema::create for creating
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of all the integer fields is `autoincrement`, not `size`. Setting this to anything that's truthy will result in the field being auto incremented. This is probably not what you're attempting here.

I suggest you use any of the available methods for the size:
`tinyInteger`, `smallInteger`, `mediumInteger`, `integer`, `bigInteger`,
`unsignedTinyInteger`, `unsignedSmallInteger`, `unsignedMediumInteger`, `unsignedInteger`, `unsignedBigInteger`

Or any of the auto incrementing helpers:
`tinyIncrements`, `smallIncrements`, `mediumIncrements`, `increments`, `bigIncrements`

Also, you don't need `change()` unless you're actually changing the table structure in a follow-up migration.

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L756-L759
Available column types: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types
Modifying columns: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes

Comment: So funny. This answer is just a combination of the two existing answers.